# ElementUI : right submenu appears truncated (CSS)

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I need a top right menu in the nav bar. But on mouseover, the sub-menu appears truncated above the window.

How to make it appear so that the right of the submenu is next to the window border ?

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app'
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/1.4.7/theme-default/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/1.4.7/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <el-menu class="el-menu" mode="horizontal">
        <el-submenu index="4" style="float: right;">
            <template slot="title"><i class="el-icon-menu"></i></template>
            <el-menu-item index="4-1"><i class="el-icon-setting"></i> Settings</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="4-2"><i class="el-icon-information"></i> About</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="4-3"><i class="el-icon-circle-close"></i> Logout</el-menu-item>
        </el-submenu>
    </el-menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the position properties of the menu in the css. Reset the `left` value, and add `right: 0`

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app'
    });
```

```css
.el-menu--horizontal .el-submenu > .el-menu {
  left: initial !important;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/1.4.7/theme-default/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/1.4.7/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <el-menu class="el-menu" mode="horizontal">
        <el-submenu index="4" style="float: right;">
            <template slot="title"><i class="el-icon-menu"></i></template>
            <el-menu-item index="4-1"><i class="el-icon-setting"></i> Settings</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="4-2"><i class="el-icon-information"></i> About</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="4-3"><i class="el-icon-circle-close"></i> Logout</el-menu-item>
        </el-submenu>
    </el-menu>
</div>
```